# Windows Server 2012 - Hyper-V - iSCSI SAN - All Hyper-V Guests stops responding and extensive disk read/write

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, iscsi, windows-server-2012, failovercluster

We have a problem with one of our deployments of Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V with a 2 node cluster connected to a iSCSI SAN.

Our Problem

- Our problem is that for some reason all of the VMs stops responding
  or responds very slowly and you can for instance not send
  CTRL-ALT-DEL to a VM in the Hyper-V console, or for instance start
  task manager when already logged in.

Symptoms (i.e. this happens, or does not happen, at the same time)

- I we look at resource monitor on the host then we see that there is
  often an extensive read from a VHDX of one of the VMs (40-60 Mbyte/s)
  and a combined write speed to many files in \HarddiskVolume5\System
  Volume Information{}.
- The combined network speed to the iSCSI SAN is about 500-600 Mbit/s.
  When this happens it is usually during and after a VSS ShadowCopy
  backup, but has also happens during hours where no backup should be
  running (i.e. during daytime when the backup has finished hours ago
  according to the log files). There is however not that extensive
  writes to the backup file that is created on an external hard drive
  and this does not seem to happen during all backups (we have manually
  checked a few times, but it is hard to say since this error does not
  seem leave any traces in event viewer).
- We cannot find any indication that the VMs themself detect any
  problem and we see no increase of errors (for example storage related
  errors) in the eventlog inside the VMs.
- The QNAP uses about 50% processing Power on all cores.
- We see no dropped packets on the switch.

Please see full article here:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/70612d46-1d51-43fb-b5db-1302af2ef4ae

You can provide an answer in both places.

Comment: Just want to confirm that the cluster drive is formatted CSVFS